# Could you explain what is the fk_PerOrders in the below sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query is from this link  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int NOT NULL,
OrderNo int NOT NULL,
P_Id int,
PRIMARY KEY (O_Id),
CONSTRAINT fk_PerOrders FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)
REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`fk_PerOrders` is the name given to the constraint.

Say in the future you wanted to remove the foreign key. You could do this by referring to it by name:

```
ALTER TABLE orders DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_PerOrders;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just a name for the constraint. See [**Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]
```

In your code the `fk_PerOrders` is that `symbol`:

> If the CONSTRAINT symbol clause is given, the symbol value, if used,
>   must be unique in the database. A duplicate symbol will result in an
>   error similar to: ERROR 1022 (2300): Can't write; duplicate key in
>   table '#sql- 464_1'. If the clause is not given, or a symbol is not
>   included following the CONSTRAINT keyword, a name for the constraint
>   is created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

fk_PerOrders is the name given to the constrain, it will be used by the database client.
Later you can delete it using his name.

Answer (score 0):

You must have missed this part.

"The FOREIGN KEY constraint is used to prevent actions that would destroy links between tables.

The FOREIGN KEY constraint also prevents invalid data from being inserted into the foreign key column, because it has to be one of the values contained in the table it points to."

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)
REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
```